# scanf uses pointers to **variable**, not **variables themselves**

Tags: c

I am reading "the GNU C Programming" about pointer [The GNU C Programming Tutorial](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Pointers.html#Pointers)

It states that:

> However, scanf uses pointers to **variables**, not **variables themselves**. For example, the following code reads an integer from the keyboard:

```
int my_integer;
scanf ("%d", &my_integer);
```

It's twisted confusing to understand "variable" and "variable itself".
Could you provide any tips?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a *value* and a *variable*? In C you can never pass a variable as an argument, but a *pointer to a variable* is a kind of value, so a function like `scanf` needs a pointer to a variable. Syntactically, a variable in a function call's argument list is simply evaluated and its value is used as the argument instead.

Comment: You are emphasising wrongly. It should read "*... uses **pointers to** variable, **not** variables **themselves**.*" Also "*pointers to*" could be replaced by "*address of*".

Comment: It's `(pointers to variables), not (variables themselves)` rather than `pointers to (variables, not variables themselves)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule at play here is clause 6.3.2.1, paragraph 2, in the 2018 C standard (and the same or similar clauses in earlier standards). This rule tells us when a name represents the object and when it is converted to a value (so it can no longer be used to access the object).

A variable is actually two things: an object, which is a region of storage (a byte for a `char`, several bytes for an `int`, possibly many bytes for a structure or an array) and an identifier (its name).

When you use the name in source code, it is an *lvalue*, which designates an object.<sup>1,2</sup>. Clause 6.3.2.1, paragraph 2, tells us that when an *lvalue* is used with unary `&`, it is **not** converted to a value. It designates the object, and then the `&` operator can provide the address of that object.

This paragraph also tells us this conversion is not performed when an lvalue is used with `sizeof`, `++`, or `--`, or when it is the left operand of `.` (for accessing structures) or of `=` (for assignment).

Otherwise, the lvalue is converted to its value.<sup>3</sup>

Thus, in `scanf("%d", my_integer)`, `my_integer` is converted to the value in it. Only this value is passed to `scanf`, and therefore `scanf` has no way of accessing the object. When you write `scanf("%d", &my_integer)`, the `&` takes the address of `my_integer`, and this address is passed to `scanf`. This gives `scanf` a way to access the object (by its address).

Identifiers used in expressions are not the only lvalues in C. Another common lvalue is the expression `*p`, where `p` is a pointer. This is an lvalue, effectively the same as if the name of the object that `p` points to had been used.<sup>4</sup>

## Notes

<sup>1</sup> The term “lvalue” comes from its historic appearance on the left side of an expression as in `a = 3`. Since `a` is being changed by the assignment, the name “a” must provide access to the object. It cannot be just a value.

<sup>2</sup> The C standard says an lvalue *potentially* designates an object, but we do not need to consider the exceptions here.

<sup>3</sup> Also, if the lvalue designates an array, it is not converted to its value. However, a different conversion is performed in most circumstances; an array is converted to a pointer to its first element.

<sup>4</sup> Other lvalues are string literals, references to structure members (such as `s.member` or `p->member`), and compound literals. lvalues can also “pass through” certain other operators such as parentheses or `_Generic`.

Answer (score 5):

This is confusing wording. Perhaps a clearer way to put it is that `scanf` needs to know where to put the values that it will read in. Giving it the current value of a variable doesn't do it any good (unless that variable contains the address you want the values placed).

```
int my_integer;
scanf ("%d", &my_integer);
```

This passes to `scanf` the address where `my_integer`'s value is stored. Without the `&`, you'd be passing it the value of `my_integer`, which would be garbage since the variable hasn't been initialized.

The phrase "not variables themselves" is confusing. Perhaps "not values themselves" would be more helpful, because sometimes variables do contain pointers to where values are stored.